# Low Search: how to sort?

Tags: low-search

Is there a way to sort Low Search results? Say I wanted to sort by {title} in ascending order. Or sort by and {age} field in descending order. Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anna is right. You can just use the `orderby=""` and `sort=""` parameters in the Results tag.

To let the end user choose, [you can use all `{exp:channel:entries}` parameters as input fields](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#form-tag) in the Form tag, so that includes the `orderby` and `sort` parameters.

For example:

```
Sort by <select name="orderby">
    <option value="">Relevance</option>
    <option value="title">Title</option>
    <option value="date">Entry Date</option>
    <option value="custom_field">Custom Field</option>
    ...
</select>

in <select name="sort">
   <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
   <option value="desc">Descending</option>
</select> order.
```

Comment: Does this mean I would have to have 2 form fields: `orderby` and `sort`? I couldn't just have 1 drop down that has the following options for sorting: By Price (ASC), By Price (DESC), etc.?

Comment: if you don't want visitors to have to select the sort, or you just want predefined settings, then you can use javascript to set a hidden form input field for the sort parameter. Using jQuery or onChange, you can set the hidden 'sort' field to 'asc' or 'desc'.

Comment: I was hoping for a non-JS solution. The JS solution is probably more user friendly than having 2 fields, though.

Comment: It isn't possible to combine the two parameters into one at the moment, but I can see how that would be a nice feature request.

Comment: `<option value="price:asc">Price - Lowest to Highest</option>` - something like that? Feature requested!

Comment: Feature implemented in 2.2.0! Use `orderby_sort="price|asc"` as a parameter or its input equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

With Low Search you can sort by relevance which is the default setting or you can sort by using any parameter the native [**channel:entries tag**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#parameters) can use.

You'll probably want to use the [**orderby=""**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#orderby) parameter:

```
orderby="title"
orderby="name_of_field"
```

Comment: What if I wanted the users to choose the `orderby`? Can I provide it as a `<select>` in Low Search form? That way Low Search results will just take it as part of its parameters? I don't want to hard code the `orderby` parameter in the opening tag pair.